# How to avoid temporary object on the stack when using the allocator concept?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

The following code tries to create nodes of a binary tree and return a boost::shared_ptr() to it.

```
void create_node(shared_ptr &in,
            unsigned var_name,
            shared_ptr left=shared_ptr(),
            shared_ptr right=shared_ptr()) {
  typename nodes::pointer p = A.allocate(1);
  // a temporary node element is created on the stack here.
  A.construct(p, (node(var_name, left, right)));
  in = shared_ptr(p);
}
```

Looking into the libstdc++ code I've found out that the std::allocator functions I'm calling look like this:

```
pointer
allocate(size_type __n, const void* = 0)
{ 
  if (__n > this->max_size())
    std::__throw_bad_alloc();
  return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n * sizeof(_Tp)));
}

void 
construct(pointer __p, const _Tp& __val) 
{ ::new((void *)__p) _Tp(__val); }
```

The allocator uses in-placement new to separate the allocation of the memory and the construction of the object. Thus it's possible to get a large amount of elements and calls only the constructor when an object is really needed.

The `create_node` function creates a single object by using the allocator concept and uses shared_ptr to call the destructor whenever needed. To make these single allocations cheap I want to replace the allocator later (hence I want an allocator that uses pool allocation).

When I call this function it will create a temporary instance on the stack and then copies the elements of the node to heap location. How can I force the compiler to create the object in place immediately? Thus I want an inverted Named Return Value Optimization (NRVO). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`allocate_shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/ee410605.aspx).

Comment: I'm using Linux and I'm stuck with C++03

Comment: Then use `std::tr1::allocate_shared`, from `<tr1/memory>`.

Comment: unfortunately tech release 1 is not part of C++03 but part of C++0x, but thanks for the hint I might just add experimental features if the compiler actually supports C++11.

Comment: Or perhaps [`boost::allocate_shared`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html), since the question is about `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Alex: No, not quite. There's no TR1 *in* C++11, since C++11 actually contains all those things as part of the actual standard. Rather, TR1 is a library for C++98/03 that predates the new standard and has been shipped with popular compilers for a long, long time.

Comment: I just looked in the wrong places for documentation. Thanks for all the input.
@KerrekSB: It seems to me using TR1 is rather non portable, especially if I can use boost directly. as soon as the code-base shall be declared as ready for C++11  the header locations are different a third time anyway.

Comment: @Alex: Well, yeah. If you already decided to use Boost, you can use some Boost TR1 module that will pick the actual implementation from the best available source... anyway, with judicious typedefing it shouldn't be such a dramatic hassle to change this later, but just pick whichever feels the most stable for your purposes.